# Поддерживает ли HyperSQL транзакции для файловой базы данных

Tags: java, javafx, embedded

Разрабатываю приложение на Java, в котором будет толстый клиент JavaFX и локальная база данных HyperSQL, но вопрос встал клином по двум моментам. Хочется упаковать приложение в дистрибутив, и поэтому кажется удобным использовать embeded файловую БД HyperSQL, но в таком случае будут ли работать транзакции и Lazy Load. В приложении используется Spring + JPA.
Или же в случае файловой базы о транзакциях и ленивой загрузке (JPA) стоит забыть?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снят, прочитал в документации и решил запускать и стопарить сервер HyperSQL из приложения, оказывается такое возможно. И тогда будут доступны и транзакции и ленивая загрузка с JPA. Хотя думаю транзакции Spring были бы доступны и в файловом режиме HyperSQL.